# Generate and execute R, Python, etc.., script from within bash script

Tags: python, r, bash

I have been trying to find a solution for this for a while but haven't found anything satisfactory yet. I write a lot of bash scripts, but sometimes I want to use R or Python as part of the script. Right now, I end up having to write two scripts; the original bash script to perform the first half of the task, and the R or Python script to perform the second half of the task. I call the R/Python script from within the bash script.

I am not satisfied with this solution because it splits my program over two files, which increases the chances of things getting out of sync, more files to track, etc.. Is there a way to write a block of text that contains the entirety of my R/Python script, and then have bash spit it out into a file and pass arguments to it & execute it? Is there an easier solution? This is more complicated than passing simple one-liners to R/Python because it usually involves creating and manipulating objects over several steps.

Comment: Have you considered using [IPython](http://ipython.org/)? It was geared towards solving such problems. If that doesn't work for you, consider that you can use `os.system` to do bash work from within python, and `pandas` let's you do a lot of `R` things in python

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I have seen IPython. Right now I accomplish mostly the same with just RStudio, either with knitr + Rmd/Rnw to compile all code, or just copy/paste the bash commands into terminal and run R in the IDE. I work in a Linux environment using bash and command line tools so a solution that allows me to embed complex R scripts within my bash scripts would be most convenient.

Comment: You can run bash/shell/python/etc commands in R markdown documents. You could actually just use an Rscript with a call to knit referencing an R markdown document.

Comment: Let's face it: the reason to split the programs in half was because it was more convenient to do some things in one language and other things were more convenient in the other. And what you want is to streamline your scripts without sacrificing convenience. Bad news: you can not have the cake and eat it. And the need to install  an interpreter just because isn't really best practice. My advice: learn one language *really* well, so that even complicated tasks aren't that problematic. I'd go with Python, split down problems into smaller ones and make heavy use of pipes.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg that is good in theory but I need to integrate scripts that perform complex actions using command-line programs then parse and process the output. Bash can handle the former and some of the latter just fine but when you need to generate reports, plots & figures, or use packages that are only available in a certain programming language it is not feasible.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for pipes than to call one script in language A from within the other written in language B.

Comment: Somewhat agreeing with Markus... I needed similar ability for the past year and recently realized that python (with pandas and matplotlib) could do all of that. Before I was trying bash + gnuplot, and other things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are probably lots of solutions, but this one works:

```
#!/bin/bash
## do stuff
R --slave <<EOF
  ## R code
  set.seed(101)
  rnorm($1)
EOF
```

If you want the flexibility to pass additional bash arguments to R, I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
## do stuff
R --slave --args $@ <<EOF
  ## R code
  set.seed(101)
  args <- as.numeric(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))
  do.call(rnorm,as.list(args))
EOF
```

- this allows a flexible number of arguments, but assumes they will all be numeric
- it also assumes that all parameters will be passed through from the bash script to the R sub-script

obviously you could relax these, e.g. refer to parameters positionally

Comment: Ben, do you know what the syntax would be for this if you wanted to pass arguments to it for evaluation in R? EDIT: Nevermind just realized that the line `rnorm($1)` already includes this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update Ben. I was messing with it on my own and found that you can also use `-` syntax to direct `Rscript` to read the stdin input from the `E0F` heredoc block in lieu of a real file, and then pass arguments as normal: `Rscript --slave - "$1" <<EOF` and then `args <- commandArgs(TRUE)` within the heredoc as with normal `Rscript` argument passing.

I'm not sure if there's an advantage to this method but it should allow any sort of argument to be passed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example for python, similar to [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769363/3430492)'s answer

```
#!/bin/bash
python << EOF
print 'Hello $1'
EOF
```

output:

```
> sh test.sh "world"

Hello world
```

### -----------------------------------------------

You can pass variables from bash to python too:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++)) do
python << EOF
print 'Hello world $i times'
EOF
done
```

output:

```
> sh test.sh 5

Hello world 1 times
Hello world 2 times
Hello world 3 times
Hello world 4 times
Hello world 5 times
```

Importing pandas, numpy, matplotlib, and others for normal jobs works fine.