# How do you run R commands directly from a bash script-not by calling another R script?

Tags: r, bash

I don't know why no one else has asked this.

In a regular interactive bash environment, it goes like this:

```
R
some r code here
q("no")
```

But I can't do this from a submitted job. It's very annoying. I'm already calling too many scripts for a relatively minor job. I don't want to create more scripts that literally have 1 or 2 lines each. I do want to do this through R.

Comment: Is the `-e` option sufficient if you have very short/simple scripts?  e.g. `Rscript -e "print('my script')"`

Comment: That could work for one-liners, thank you. But, I believe this still stands for short scripts that are 4 or 5 lines.

Comment: It's a bit clunky, but following @cdeterman suggestion: `Rscript -e "a <- 1:10; b <- a*2; b" works

Comment: is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769018/generate-and-execute-r-python-etc-script-from-within-bash-script/33769363#33769363